# Как сделать навигацию ссылок в каждый отдельный фрагмент, то есть чтоб открывалась каждая вкладка по отдельности без скролла

Tags: javascript, reactjs

На данный момент страница выглядит как Landing Page, то есть при нажатии на ссылку из header.js листает вниз к странице, хотелось бы сделать чтоб без скролла он открывал каждую ссылку по отдельности внутри

**App JS**

```
import "./App.scss";
import Header from "./components/Header";
import Home from "./components/Home";
import AboutUs from "./components/About";
import Services from "./components/Services";
import Resume from "./components/Resume";
import Portfolio from "./components/Portfolio";
import Testimonials from "./components/Testimonials";
import Contact from "./components/Contact";
import Footer from "./components/Footer";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import ClassicHeader from "./components/ClassicHeader";
import { commonConfig } from "./config/commonConfig";
import TermsAndConditions from "./components/TermsAndConditions";
import Disclaimer from "./components/Disclaimer";
import PreLoader from "./components/Preloader";
import { Tooltip } from "./components/Tooltip";

function App() {
    
  const classicHeader = commonConfig.classicHeader;
  const darkTheme = commonConfig.darkTheme;

  const handleNavClick = (section) => {
    document.getElementById(section).scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
  };

  const [scrollTopVisible, setScrollTopVisible] = useState(false);
  
  const [isLoading, setisLoading] = useState(true);
  useEffect(() => {
    const loadingTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
      setisLoading(false);
    }, 1000);
    return () => {
      clearTimeout(loadingTimeout);
    };
  }, []);

  const checkScrollTop = () => {
    let scrollTopBtn = document.getElementById("back-to-top");

    if (scrollTopBtn) {
      if (
        document.body.scrollTop > 400 ||
        document.documentElement.scrollTop > 400
      ) {
        setScrollTopVisible(true);
      } else {
        setScrollTopVisible(false);
      }
    }
  };

  if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", checkScrollTop);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div
        style={{ position: "relative" }}
        className={classicHeader ? "" : "side-header"}
      >
        {isLoading && <PreLoader></PreLoader>}

        <div id="main-wrapper">
          {classicHeader ? (
            <ClassicHeader handleNavClick={handleNavClick}></ClassicHeader>
          ) : (
            <Header handleNavClick={handleNavClick}></Header>
          )}

          <div id="content" role="main">
            <Home
              classicHeader={classicHeader}
              darkTheme={darkTheme}
              handleNavClick={handleNavClick}
            ></Home>
            <Portfolio
              classicHeader={classicHeader}
              darkTheme={darkTheme}
            ></Portfolio>
            <AboutUs
              classicHeader={classicHeader}
              darkTheme={darkTheme}
            ></AboutUs>
            <Resume
              classicHeader={classicHeader}
              darkTheme={darkTheme}
            ></Resume>
            <Contact
              classicHeader={classicHeader}
              darkTheme={darkTheme}
            ></Contact>
          </div>
 
        </div>

        {/* back to top */}
        
        
        
        <Tooltip text="Back to Top" placement="left">
          <span
            id="back-to-top"
            className="rounded-circle"
            style={{ display: scrollTopVisible ? "inline" : "none" }}
            onClick={() => {
              window.scrollTo({ top: 0, behavior: "smooth" });
            }}
          >
            <i className="fa fa-chevron-up"></i>
          </span>
        </Tooltip>

        <TermsAndConditions darkTheme={darkTheme}></TermsAndConditions>
        <Disclaimer darkTheme={darkTheme}></Disclaimer>
      </div>
    </>
  );

}

export default App;
```

**Header JS**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Tooltip } from "./Tooltip";
import { Link } from "react-scroll";

const Header = ({ classicHeader, darkTheme, homeRef, handleNavClick }) => {
  const [isNavModalClose, setIsNavModalClose] = useState(true);
  return (
    <header id="header" className="sticky-top">
      {/* Navbar */}
      
      <nav className="primary-menu navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark border-bottom-0">
        <div className="container-fluid position-relative h-100 flex-lg-column ps-3 px-lg-3 pt-lg-3 pb-lg-2">
          {/* Logo */}
          
          <Link
            smooth
            duration={500}
            style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
            to="home"
            className="mb-lg-auto mt-lg-4"
            onClick={(e) => {
              e.preventDefault();
              setIsNavModalClose(true);
            }}
          >
          
              <img
                className="imag"
                src="images/profil.jpg"
                title="I'm Simone"
                alt="profile"
              />
          </Link>
          {/* Logo End */}
          <div
            id="header-nav"
            className={
              isNavModalClose
                ? "collapse navbar-collapse my-lg-auto "
                : "show navbar-collapse  my-lg-auto"
            }
          >
            <ul className="navbar-nav  my-lg-auto py-lg-3">
              <li className="nav-item">
                <Link
                  target={homeRef}
                  className="nav-link "

                  style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
                  activeClass="active"
                  spy
                  
                  to="portfolio"
                  onClick={(e) => {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    setIsNavModalClose(true);
                  }}
                >
                  Case
                </Link>
              </li>
              <li className="nav-item">
                <Link
                  className="nav-link "

                  style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
                  activeClass="active"
                  spy
                  to="about"
                  onClick={(e) => {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    setIsNavModalClose(true);
                  }}
                >
                  Price
                </Link>
              </li>
          
              <li className="nav-item">
                <Link
                  className="nav-link "

                  style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
                  activeClass="active"
                  spy
                  to="resume"
                  onClick={(e) => {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    setIsNavModalClose(true);
                  }}
                >
                  Resume
                </Link>
              </li>

              <li className="nav-item">
                <Link
                  className="nav-link "

                  style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
                  activeClass="active"
                  spy
                  to="contact"
                  onClick={(e) => {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    setIsNavModalClose(true);
                  }}
                >
                  Contact
                </Link>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
         
          <button
            onClick={(e) => {
              setIsNavModalClose(!isNavModalClose);
            }}
            className={
              isNavModalClose ? "navbar-toggler" : "navbar-toggler show"
            }
            id="navbar-toggler"
            type="button"
          >
            <span />
            <span />
            <span />
          </button>
        </div>
      </nav>
      {/* Navbar End */}
    </header>
  );
};

export default Header;
```

Comment: Такое можно организовать роутингом... Суть там как раз такая. На некую ссылку (изменение УРЛ) рендерится свой контент.